# After upgrading to Java 1.8 on Mac OS Yosemite javac still shows 1.6

Tags: java, macos, operating-system

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202516/after-upgrading-to-java8-javac-still-shows-1-7) ... the solutions offered don't work for me.  First, folder `/Library/Java/Extensions` is empty and `~/Library/Java` folder does not exist on my OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 system.

I did do a Java update to 1.8 from the Oracle site, and got this part to work: 
java -version returns: 
`java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)`, but
javac -version returns a no program found error: 
`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javac" (-1)`

The directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is also empty.

Lastly, if I do: 
`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_31 --exec javac -version
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8.0_31".
javac 1.6.0_65`  Notice how `--exec javac -version` in the previous one-liner does find the javac, but it reports the old 1.6.  How do I fix my paths so that javac works?  Here is my PATH and JAVA_HOME:

`mbp_host$ echo $JAVA_HOME` returns

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

`mbp_host$ echo $PATH` returns

`/usr/local/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

Comment: Check out this solution I posted in [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6808987).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work around than solution. Mac just always seems to point to this location despite updates to path, java_home :

[image]

After installing java8 from Oracle to compile I explicitly point to the compiler : `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac MyClass.java`