# Mac OS ElCapitan: java -version command not working

Tags: java, python, macos, nltk, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to make Standford NER package to work on my mac. Using anaconda and python 2.7 (iPython notebook). I was following the steps given here:
http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford. While executing the last step, it gave me `UnsupportedClassVersionError.."xy.z" is "52.0"` which means I need to upgrade to java 8. 
I upgraded to Java 8, but my `java -version` command still showing java 7. So I tried to fix it using the solution given here: [After upgrading to Java8, javac still shows 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202516/after-upgrading-to-java8-javac-still-shows-1-7). Instead of removing, I renamed the directory. These are the following commands I exec:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
mv Current Current_Old
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/ Current
```

Then after that `java -version` command is not working. I realized the directory name is incorrect and tried to replace it back using `mv Current_Old Current`, still the command is not working.

how can I restore my java?

Comment: Disclaimer: Not a mac user. But I think `rm Current` should remove the symbolic link. If you would like to be safe, i think `unlink Current` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get it working again! All I did was restored legacy Java 6 from this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

Then `java -version` was even showing me the latest version which is Java 1.8. Able to start Java IDE now.